# NGINX start fail after adding config file for roundcube

Tags: nginx

I have created a web-server that runs Pelican on nginx.  Here is the config file for my web-server contained in /etc/nginx/sites-available/larryfritts.com:

```
server {
    server_name www.larryfritts.com;

    # Rewrite www to non-www
    rewrite ^(.*) http://larryfritts.com$1 permanent;
}

server {
    # Listening ports
    listen 80;      ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    listen [::]:80; ## listen for ipv6

    # Make site accessible from domain
    server_name larryfritts.com;

    # Root directory
    root /var/www/larryfritts.com/public_html;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    # Logs
    access_log /var/www/larryfritts.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/larryfritts.com/logs/error.log;

    # Includes
    include global/restrictions.conf;
}
```

Everything was working fine.  I decided to add a mail-server and roundcube and so created another config file for roundcube.  This is found in /etc/nginx/sites-available/roundcube:

```
server {
    server_name mail.larryfritts.com;
        listen 80;
    return 301 https://mail.yourdomain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name mail.larryfritts.com;
        listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS server
server {
    listen 443 ssl spdy default_server;
    server_name mail.larryfritts.com;
    root /usr/share/nginx/roundcube;
    index index.html index.php;
    autoindex off;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/private/ssl-chain-mail-larryfritts.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/ssl-key-decrypted-mail-larryfritts.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1 SSLv3;
    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5:!DSS;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ecdh_curve secp521r1;

    # Client auth via certs
#   ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/private/yourdomain.crt;
#   ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/ssl/private/yourdomain.crt;
#   ssl_verify_client on;

    location / {
#       if ($ssl_client_s_dn !~* "you@yourdomain.com") {
#           return 301 http://www.jurassicsystems.com/;
#       }
#       error_page 403 @fallback;
    }

    location ~ ^/(README|INSTALL|LICENSE|CHANGELOG|UPGRADING)$ {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/(bin|SQL)/ {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/.*\.php {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass php5-fpm-sock;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    }
```

Both of these files are sym-linked to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

When I try to restart nginx I get a failure:

```
service nginx restart
 * Restarting nginx nginx        [fail]
```

I am assuming that I have a conflict in my two config files but this is the first server I have setup and I am not understanding it well enough yet.

Comment: `sudo nginx -t` will show you error

Comment: Thank you.  That led me in the right direction and I was able to determine I needed to update nginx and I had left of a closing brace.  I did not know that trick, one for the file.